# How to initialize object property on first access in php 7?

Tags: php, oop

let's say i have this class:

```php
class DB {
   private DBConnection $connection;
   private string $databaseName;

   public function __construct($databaseName) {
      $this->databaseName = $databaseName;
   }
   private function initConnection(): void {
      if (!isset($this->connection)) {
         $this->connection = new DBConnection($this->databaseName);
      }
   }
   public function query($str): array {
      $this->initConnection();
      return $this->connection->query($str);
   }
   public function something(): void {
      $this->initConnection();
      $this->connection->something();
   }
}
```

Then I have some code that may or **may not** call the `->query` / `->something` methods, depending on the situation.

How can I avoid calling `initConnection` in every single place where `$this->connection` has to be used?
I only want to initialize it IF it is accessed, on its first access.

I already tried with the magic method `__get` but it only gets called if `$connection` is not in the class definition.

Another way is to create an accessor method (`getConnection`) which calls `initConnection` and use `$this->getConnection()` (returning the connection object, instead of `void`) instead of `$this->connection`, but still, `initConnection` would get called for nothing.

The problem with this approach is that I could accidentally still use `$this->connection` instead of the getter method; is there a way I can disallow the direct use of the property?

Comment: Which database are you using (MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server, etc)? Which extension are you using (mysqli, PDO, etc)? Please add the corresponding tag(s) to your question.

Comment: @dakis actually, the example is just an example. my question is not about databases, it is about classes and properties initialization.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you are correct by concluding to use a (private) `getConnection` method to instantiate the connection only on its first use. And have the rest of the class method use `getConnection()` instead of `$this->connection`.

However, I also believe you are experiencing the downside of the singleton pattern. Perhaps consider refactoring out the actual `DBConnection`, and pass it as a constructor argument (dependency) to `DB`. You can then provide implementations of `DBConnection` that support lazy loading and singletons.